# Editing existing answers by adding additional information

Tags: discussion, support

I'm pretty new to AskUbuntu's **review** section. IMHO, I review by doing some search before taking any decisions. But, hey! that is me.

My question is, do we allow editing averagely voted answers with adding few more information? e.g.:

- [What is the linux-image-extra package for and do I need it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153023/what-is-the-linux-image-extra-package-for-and-do-i-need-it)

Also, some users just edit a single letter for the sake of earning points. In such scenarios, how do we handle?

Comment: I don't get your point here, the answer you link was edited, by the same user that posted the answer, to include some info brought up in the comments, the OP can edit there answer however they like, it is common practice to edit your answer with requested information. In this case, you would not see that in the review queue anyway. The question was just streamlined (that is very common here), I don't see any added information there. Also, this question was not edited since 2014 and the answer 2012, what review queue did this even come up in ?

Comment: @markkirby,,, sorry my bad... I've linked the question which came under review but not the actual revision screen.... However, below Oli's answer made it more clear to me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just editing out a "Hello" is a waste of an edit and reviewer time. It does not make the post *better*, it does not make the issue any clearer. All it does it waste review time.

Using [your example's revision log](https://askubuntu.com/posts/153023/revisions), I'd say:

- #6 was a waste. It should have been rejected.
- #5 Was good. It fixed many other things and **made the post better**.
- #3 and #4 were a bit washy but didn't require multiple people to approve them.
- #2 again made the post better. It does edit out the "Thank you" at the end but it does more at the same time.

So in cases like Revision #6, reject them. I think there is a "petty edit" reason in there but otherwise just explain that it doesn't actually make the post any better.

If you see an edit like Rev #6 on a post like the original —where the post still needs a lot of work doing to it— reject it but improve it at the same time. By all means cut out the small-talk but make sure everything else is polished up at the same time.

But don't conflate small edits with petty edits. A small edit could completely change the meaning of something (or fix it). Use your discretion and look for overall value when reviewing suggested edits.

Comment: Thank you, Oli... This is exactly what I was looking for.. Thank for clearing out the doubt. :)